# Bash positional parameters command line sorting issues

Tags: linux, bash

Working on this assignment.

> Write a Bash script, insert-sort.sh, which sorts a list of command line parameters in ascending order. For example, your command will look something like:
>   $ insert-sort.sh 7 2 3 9 -1 and type enter.
>   Your program will return: -1 2 3 7 9

This is what I have so far

```
array=();
for param in "$@"; do
    if [ -z "$array" ]; then
        array[0]="$param";     
    else
        array[param]="$param";
    fi
done
echo ${array[@]}
```

The problem when I try to test the script, I get inconsistent answer. Sorted when it is not supposed to.

For example, if I run `'/././BASH/insert-sort.sh' 1 3 2` I get 1 2 3

if I run `'/././BASH/insert-sort.sh' 4 2 3` I get 4 2 3

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter isn't being sorted correctly. You're always assigning it to index 0, regardless of its value. Every other `$param` goes into the param'th slot.

Comment: Yes, I know. But 3 2 gets sorted to 2 3 in first and not in second attempt. Thanks for reply btw.

Comment: _"There is nothing in this script that sorts at all."_ With JohnKugelman's fix, yes, the code does sort.  That is the way bash arrays work. (It won't work on negative numbers, though.)